# New PNY 64 GB 3.0 USB Thumb Drive Not Showing up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive

Just bought this thumb drive, I plug it into my desktop, and nothing shows up in File Manager or anything else.  It is listed in my Device Manager, but doesn't seem to be recognized fully.  The thumb drive is slowly flashing red.  I also plugged it into my DVR, and it is not recognized there.  My desktop recognizes USB 3.0 drives, as I've plugged in my portable USB 3-0 hard drive.  When I first plugged it in, I got a message saying the device drivers were being loaded, and it then told me that the device was available.  But no.  Rebooted my computer, etc.  Still nothing.  Should I return the piece of junk to Amazon for my money back?

Answer (score -1):

It *could* be faulty, but more likely it just needs formatting. Follow these instructions and see how you go (it's a sandisk website but procedure is the same):

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/107/~/formatting-a-drive-or-device-using-disk-management

When you choose between formatting as exFAT and NTFS, check what your DVR supports if you need to use it on that too.